# Why am I getting handshake failure Apollo client error (with EPROTO errno)?

Tags: authentication, ssl, next.js, apollo-client

I'm using `apollo-boost: ^0.4.3` with next.js. I recently added cookie authentication to my website. The biggest change was adding headers and `credentials: 'include'` to `ApolloClient` constructor. In addition in the `server.js` which starts express server for next.js I added this block:

```
const getServer = (isDevHttps, expressApp) => {
  if (isDevHttps) {
    process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
    const httpsServerOptions = {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('cert', 'localhost.key')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('cert', 'localhost.crt'))
    };

    console.info('creating https server');
    return createServer(httpsServerOptions, expressApp);
  }

  return expressApp;
};
```

because I needed to run in https in development. Everything worked in development (I was using https://localhost:3000 for client and https://localhost:443 for the graphql backend server). However when I push ed my code to staging where nginx serves static files and AWS hosts the instance I started getting this error:

```
ApolloError: Network error: request to https://beta.leafreport.com/graphql/ failed, reason: write EPROTO 140426009438016:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1536:SSL alert number 40

    at new ApolloError (/src/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:92:26)
    at /src/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1588:34
    at /src/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2008:15
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /src/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2006:26
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (/src/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2004:20)
    at /src/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1483:29
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  graphQLErrors: [],
  networkError: FetchError: request to https://staging.mysite.com/graphql/ failed, reason: write EPROTO 140426009438016:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1536:SSL alert number 40
```

The first time when I pushed the code `isDevHttps` was `true` by mistake and `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` was set to 0. Afterwards I made sure that `isDevHttps` is `false` and redeployed. The SSL certificate we use is provided by AWS Cloudfront.

This is the init code for Apollo Client:

```
import withApollo from 'next-with-apollo';
import ApolloClient, { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-boost';
import { graphql_url } from 'my-config';
import { IntrospectionFragmentMatcher } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import introspectionQueryResultData from '../../fragmentTypes.json';

const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
  introspectionQueryResultData
});

function createClient({ ctx, headers, initialState }) {
  return new ApolloClient({
    credentials: 'include',
    uri: graphql_url,
    cache: new InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher }).restore(initialState || {}),
    headers
  });
}

export default withApollo(createClient, { getDataFromTree: 'ssr' });
```

this is my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.5.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.3",
    "apollo-mocked-provider": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "clean-css": "^4.2.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "dotenv-load": "^2.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.3.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "helmet": "^3.18.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "next": "^9.0.1",
    "next-plugin-custom-babel-config": "^1.0.2",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^2.3.1",
    "next-with-apollo": "^4.2.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react-apollo": "^3.0.0",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^2.5.0",
    "react-google-login": "^3.2.1",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.0.1",
    "react-minimal-pie-chart": "^4.2.0",
    "react-motion-drawer": "^3.1.0",
    "supports-webp": "^2.0.1",
    "express-device": "^0.4.2"
  }
```

This is dev.conf in nginx (it's ok that ssl is commented out because the certificate comes from cloudfront):

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;

    server_name staging.mysite.com;

    include not_found.inc;
    include static_resources.inc;
    include ads.inc;
    #include ssl.inc;

    location / {
        rewrite_log off;
        include redirects/redirects.conf;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/com-access.log combined;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/com-error.log notice;
        include graylog.logging;

        include proxy_pass.inc;
        auth_basic           "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Only the homepage works from serverside in my website however none other pages don't from serverside and return the handshake error from above. The homepage is a refreshhit from Cloudfront. Some pages open then when clicking on link clientside, however some don't open and result in 500 internal server error (handshake failure). So serverside never works but clientside sometimes works.

Nothing I tried has worked so far including changing AWS instance, removing headers/credentials from apollo client constructor, redeploying multiple times.

I see from the error stack that the error comes from here (node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:92:26):

```
QueryManager.prototype.broadcastQueries = function () {
  var _this = this;

  this.onBroadcast();
  this.queries.forEach(function (info, id) {
    if (info.invalidated) {
      info.listeners.forEach(function (listener) {
        if (listener) {
          listener(_this.queryStore.get(id), info.newData);
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Why would the client not be able to broadcast queries?